# How to add a Wordpress template opening and closing shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

recently i install wordpress Themeforest VideoTube Theme. But when i use codecanyon Social Locker plugin, then facing this issue. My wordpress theme only support do_shortcode

My short code is...

```
[sociallocker id="2378"]    [/sociallocker]
```

and i want to put this code in the middle position of my short code.

```
<div class="player player-small <?php print apply_filters( 'aspect_ratio' , 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9');?>">
```

Kindly help me... how can i to do this? What query i set to in my wordpress theme functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use do_shortcode like this way,

```
$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode = '<div class="player player-small <?php print apply_filters( 'aspect_ratio' , 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9');?>">';

echo do_shortcode( '[sociallocker id="2378"]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/sociallocker]' );
```

Comment: Error changed .... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'aspect_ratio' (T_STRING) in /home/

Comment: Yeah, there might be some error on the string, all there are for apostrophe, you need to fix them. But this is the way I'm showing you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
$text_to_be_wrapped = "<div class='player player-small ".apply_filters( 'aspect_ratio' , 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9')."'";

echo do_shortcode( '[sociallocker id="2378"]' . $text_to_be_wrapped . '[/sociallocker]' );
```